# Prestashop Hook,create a new custom hook

Tags: php, prestashop

I have some problem with my PrestaShop 1.6 , I just want to know how to add a custom hook on it.
I have to add a HOOK_TOP_LEFT on the left side in my home store but I dont know how...
I did this things untill now:

```
1-Create a new HOOK in the FrontController.php
$this->context->smarty->assign(array(
                'HOOK_HEADER' => Hook::exec('displayHeader'),
                'HOOK_TOP' => Hook::exec('displayTop'),
                'HOOK_LEFT_COLUMN' => ($this->display_column_left ? Hook::exec('displayLeftColumn') : ''),
                'HOOK_RIGHT_COLUMN' => ($this->display_column_right ? Hook::exec('displayRightColumn', array('cart' => $this->context->cart)) : ''),
                ****'HOOK_TOP_LEFT'** => Hook::exec('topLeft'),**
            ));
        }
```

2-Add in the database the hook
 What missing?because right now it doesnt work
 Thanks for any help!:)*

Comment: "*it doesn't work*" please edit your question and add the relevant error message.

Comment: There arent any 'error message' i just want to know how to add a custom HOOK on prestashop...thanks